# WSL cannot connect to windows through vEthernets IP

Tags: windows, networking, wsl2

So i'm trying to get X in WSL2 working. I've installed an X server on windows, which works fine.

`netstat -a -b | grep -A1 6000` shows:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6000           TOBIAS-PC:0            ABH□REN
 [GWSL_vcxsrv.exe]
```

So it listens on every adapter, which *should* include my vEthernet adapter. My vEthernet's IP on Windows is 172.22.240.1. Setting `DISPLAY` to `172.22.240.1:0.0` doesn't work, my graphical applications doesn't seem to be able to connect. **Iff** I set `DISPLAY` to my regular networks ip address, i.e. `192.168.168.25:0.0`, it works fine. WSLs default route is  `172.22.240.1`, so packets *do* arrive in Windows.

I don't really know where to start diagnosing it. To me, according to the facts I collected, it seems like services listening on 0.0.0.0 just "ignore" my vEthernet completely, as the connection obviously works, given that WSL can connect to Windows through the public (non-v) Ethernet IP and to the Internet.

Edit: I just fired Wireshark up to see the traffic. Looking at vEthernets packets, I see a SYN, followed by a few SYN retransmissions, until it gives up.

Comment: WSL2 runs in a virtualized VMs with a VMSwitch that is NATed on the Windows side. So assuming "your vEthernet adapter" is in the main Windows VM, then no, it doesn't listen on this one. And you didn't say **from where** you want to connect to the X server. If this is from a different machine than the one WSL2 is running on, you need to fiddle with the VMSwitch, or Port forward (google).

Comment: `And you didn't say from where you want to connect to the X server.` From the WSL2 VM running on the same Windows PC where the X server is running from. `WSL2 runs in a virtualized VMs with a VMSwitch that is NATed on the Windows side. So assuming "your vEthernet adapter" is in the main Windows VM, then no, it doesn't listen on this one.` Alright, I understand that it's NATed to the "outside world" through my public ethernet connection, however I don't understand why I can't listen for connections directly from WSL.

Comment: Even listening directly on `172.22.240.1` instead of `0.0.0.0` on Windows, I can't connect from WSL.